# Error - clean and build - no suitable constructor found y cannot find symbol

Tags: java, xml, java-ee, glassfish

**Tengo problemas a la hora de compilar un programa**

A la hora de hacer clean and build en netbeans, me sale el siguiente error:

> error: no suitable constructor found for User(String,String,boolean)
>                       adminList.add(new User(mail, pass, isAdmin));
>       constructor User.User() is not applicable
>         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>       constructor User.User(String,String,String,String) is not applicable
>         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

pero la clase `User` tiene un constructor que si se adapta a las necesidades, con código se ve así:

```
public class User {
private String mail;
private String pass;
private boolean admin;

public User() {}

public User(String mail, String pass, boolean admin) {
    this.mail = mail;
    this.pass = pass;
    this.admin = admin;
}

public String getMail() {
    return mail;
}

public void setMail(String mail) {
    this.mail = mail;
}

public String getPass() {
    return pass;
}

public void setPass(String pass) {
    this.pass = pass;
}

public boolean isAdmin() {
    return admin;
}

public void setAdmin(boolean admin) {
    this.admin = admin;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" + "mail=" + mail + ", pass=" + pass + ", admin=" + admin + '}';
}
```

}
y la clase donde me genera problema es una donde estoy extrayendo información desde un archivo xml, que el método es el siguiente:

```
public ArrayList<User> getAllAdmin() {
    try {
        ArrayList<User> adminList = new ArrayList<>();
        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(EXPRESSION).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = nodeList.item(i);

            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element element = (Element) node;

                String mail = element.getElementsByTagName("mail")
                        .item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                String pass = element.getElementsByTagName("pass")
                        .item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                String adminString = element.getElementsByTagName("isAdmin")
                        .item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                boolean isAdmin = false;
                if (adminString.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                    isAdmin = true;
                }
                adminList.add(new User(mail, pass, isAdmin));
            }
        }
        return adminList;
    } catch (XPathExpressionException ex) {
        System.err.println("getAllDataFromXML (Admin side) method, XPathExpressionException: " + ex.getMessage() + "\n" + Arrays.toString(ex.getStackTrace()));
    }
    return null;
}
```

Además me genera este error también, donde me dice que no encuentra el método necesario.

> error: cannot find symbol
>               if (validationArray.get(i).getMail().equalsIgnoreCase(user.getMail())) {
>     symbol:   method getMail()
>     location: variable user of type User

pero el metodo si existe, y el error se produce en este metodo:

```
 public boolean writeNewUser(User user) {
    boolean aux = false;
    ArrayList<User> validationArray = getAllAdmin();
    boolean exist = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < validationArray.size(); i++) {
        if (validationArray.get(i).getMail().equalsIgnoreCase(user.getMail())) {
            exist = true;
        }
    }

    if (!exist) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File("web/WEB-INF/file/" + xmlFile));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            /*Nodo padre: <user>*/
            Node rootNode = doc.getDocumentElement();
            /*Nueva etiqueta para el documento*/
            Element newAdmin = doc.createElement("admin");
            /*etiquetas hijas de admin*/
            Element newMail = doc.createElement("mail");
            newMail.setTextContent(user.getMail());

            Element newPass = doc.createElement("pass");
            newPass.setTextContent(user.getPass());

            Element newIsAdmin = doc.createElement("isAdmin");
            newIsAdmin.setTextContent(String.valueOf(user.isAdmin()));
            /*relacionar los nuevos elementos hijos a la etiqueta padre*/
            newAdmin.appendChild(newMail);
            newAdmin.appendChild(newPass);
            newAdmin.appendChild(newIsAdmin);
            /*relacionar los elementos con la etiqueta raiz*/
            rootNode.appendChild(newAdmin);

            /*generar archivo xml*/
            TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("web/WEB-INF/file/" + xmlFile));
            transformer.transform(source, result);
            aux = true;
        } catch (SAXException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AdminManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AdminManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AdminManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (TransformerException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AdminManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AdminManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("user already exist");
    }
    return aux;
}
```

he intentado re-hacer las clases y me sigue generando el mismo problema, no sé qué hay mal en el código. Gracias

Comment: Mira en esas clases la lista de imports: estoy seguro de que estás importando una clase User de un paquete incorrecto

Comment: @PabloLozano estoy importando bien, pero en este tiempo he descubierto que los .class no se estan generando, y cuando doy al clean and build, me pide usar metodos e incluso constructores, que borre desde hace mas de 4 dias, ejemplo tengo un constructor: `public constructor(String, String, boolean)` pero hace un tiempo, usaba un constructor que pedia: `(String, String, String, String)` y a pesar de que cambie el constructor y su llamado, me lo sigue pidiendo como si fuera el principal o si enviara los parametros necesarios para usarlo

Comment: Usas Maven? Puedes intentar actualizar el proyecto con F5 y luego Alt + F5

Comment: @PabloLozano lo que utilizo es GlassFish en Netbeans con jsp y servlets

Comment: Ah, asumía Eclipse, lo siento

Comment: @PabloLozano esque es para un trabajo de la universidad, y nos obligan a usar netbeans para los proyectos...